# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible while invoking send_keys in ubuntu headless browser through python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am having the trouble with the send_keys

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= '/home/ec2-user/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
base_url = "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/"
driver.get(base_url)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id = 'homepage_search_box']")[0].send_keys("Pink's Hot Dogs")
```

the above code working perfectly in windows but when it comes to ubuntu it trowing an error like

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: headless chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="simple_search(jQuery('#homepage_search_box').val());return false;">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <label class="sr-only" for="homepage_search_box">Company Name or Report #</label>
        <input name="homepage_search_box" id="homepage_search_box" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name or Report #" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

can any one help

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id = 'homepage_search_box']")[0]
```

it is giving selenium object perfectly
i am getting error at sending keys

Answer (score 1):

To send character sequence to the **search** box you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.ripoffreport.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.header-field#header-search-text"))).send_keys("Pink's Hot Dogs")
  # WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='header-field'][@id='header-search-text']"))).send_keys("Pink's Hot Dogs")
  print("Search Text Sent")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Search Text Sent
  ```

Comment: it is raising                                                                                                                  raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: i am just added one line extra  options.add_argument('headless')                                                                                                                       > WebDriverWait(driver, 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/s                                                                                        upport/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: everything is working on windows,But in my server it is not working (aws fedora linux)  send_keys unable to send the keys to search box

Comment: i am able to locate the element but unable to send_keys . and i am using time.sleep also to load the page

Comment: @venkatesh Update the question with the error stack trace however your error **ElementNotVisibleException** doesn't relates to **send_keys()** but _locating the element_ which I have addressed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce withought the actual url, but you can try a few things:

- sleep a couple of seconds before sending keys (the page might not be loaded)
- it might be worth trying Firefox/geckodriver instead of Chrome; I've had issues before with Chrome as well which do not seem to happen on Firefox.
- Moreover, if you have an adblocker on Chrome when copying x_path etc it can sometimes change the page structure

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah, can't seem to be able to access from the UK! 
sorry I couldn't be more useful :/

Answer (score 0):

you can try with javaScript

```
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '"+text which you want to enter+"');",webElement);
```

Comment: everything is working on windows,But in my server it is not working (aws fedora linux) send_keys unable to send the keys to search box